# How to connect to database on freewebhostingarea?

Tags: php, database, connection, hosting, server-name

Ok so i am making account system for my website. I am using freewebhostingarea as host. But i dont know what is servername(for connecting to database). Can you help me? Here is my code for connecting:

```
<?php
    $servername = "";
    $server = "root";
    $password = "my password";
    $dbName = "name";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $server, $password, $dbName);
?>
```

I dont know what is $servername for freewebhoatingarea. Pls reply.

Comment: It should be something that you find in your control panel, or get from phpMyAdmin

Comment: The hosting company can tell you this. We are not experts on specific hosting companies' practices, usually.

Comment: P.S. **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so if you have any accidental vulnerabilities in your code 
this leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: You must read the documentation on how to setup the connection using `freewebhostingarea` .

Answer (score 0):

It's all the same actually . I want you to try this 4 steps

1. After you hit create databaase it will give you an option to name/rename your database so save that name to something like a notepad for your reference

(e.g) freehosting_db_(sampledatabase)

2. Next to that it that before you hit next on the creation of database kindly remember that password that you are going to make and like the name of the website save it to a notepad so you can remember the password

(e.g) xHsnaAXa123 -> password database

3. Mostly the server always `localhost` on SOME freehosting
4. The servername is automatically generated so look for it. It will be something like

(e.g) freehosting_db_(sampledatabase)_user

And to set that up

```
$servername = "freehosting_db_(sampledatabase)_user";
$server = "localhost";
$password = "xHsnaAXa123";
$dbName = "freehosting_db_(sampledatabase)";
```

PS: This is mostly how you setup a connection from your database to your server . But it is always depends on the the hosting that you are going to use . Godadday, Hostgator, 000webhostingapp, they are all alike on how setting it up .

Comment: you said `I dont know what is $servername for freewebhoatingarea` try the `localhost` on your servername

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried to set localhost on $servername, $server, both, not $servername nor $server. I don't know what to do now.